# Showing attributes of multiple parcels on one layout using DDP with dynamic text?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, fields-attributes, data-driven-pages, layouts

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 for making maps showing the distribution of parcels and their attributes in a given area. I am working with anywhere from 20 to 50 parcels in a set, sometimes more. I often use Data Driven Pages (DDP) and dynamic text to speed the process along. My problem is that sometimes there are multiple parcels in close proximity to each other. I would like to be able to show the attributes of multiple parcels on one layout using ddp/dynamic text. How can I do this?

Update: This is an example of what I most commonly work on. I used ddp and dynamic text for the attribute data on the right of the map. I wish to use dynamic text for attributes for all parcels in the layout. How can this be accomplished? Further explanations and examples can be provided if need be.[image]

Comment: A screenshot might help understand what you are trying to do. If it's what I *think* you're trying to do, the only way I know of would be to run `Calculate Adjacent Fields` on your parcels and then insert dynamic text for each of the possible adjacency relationships. On any given page, the ones that can be filled out will display and those with no value will simply not appear.

Comment: Ah, that greatly clarifies what you are attempting to do. I thought the parcels were your DDP index layer. What you are actually trying to do is create a dynamic table in your layout that will update based on the contents of the dataframe. There is a specific tool for that but it's part of an extension. It can also be done with python scripting. Those solutions are covered at another question which I will flag this as a duplicate of.

Comment: I'm confident that what you are trying to achieve can be done but to do so as a single multi-pronged question does not fit our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend that you edit your question to "knock out" all the map elements that are distracting me from the question most important to you.  The things I would leave in/add are the data frame, the index layer, the text element, the layer that the text in the text element is derived from, how you are currently deriving the text shown and the requirement you have for enhanced text within the text element.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly; [Maplex Label Engine](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s800000026000000/) can be used alongside data driven pages to deal with complex labeling issues and may be more appropriate than dynamic text from data driven pages. Maplex Label Engine is much more robust than dynamic text via data driven pages, which are mainly for meta information like page numbers, labeling neighboring pages, titles, etc.

With Maplex Label Engine, you can address issues of orientation and placement, conflicts in labels, labeling in conjested areas, specific formatting for any of the fields in your vector data, and many other advanced labeling issues.

Comment: I don't think this question is about the labelling on the map.  Instead I think it is about making the table under the heading display information from multiple parcels.